# php 2 condition for mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what to Google about this one because I can't put the question to words. I have this line of code and I want to add another condition to it.

```
'closed_at'  => $statusName === 'closed' ? Carbon::now() : null,
```

I want it to do what it does now, but another or condition where `$statusName === 'canceled'`.

Answer (score 0):

Add another ternary where the default `null` value was:

```
'closed_at'  => (
  ($statusName === 'closed')
    ?
  Carbon::now()
    :
  (
    ($statusName === 'canceled')
      ?
    'YOUR_VALUE_HERE'
      :
    null
  )
),
```

Or use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
'closed_at' => ['closed' => Carbon::now(), 'canceled' => 'YOUR_STATUS_HERE'][$statusName] ?? null,
```

Comment: This question is either unclear or a duplicate of tens of pages on Stack Overflow.  Please make a point of closing questions that should be closed instead of answering them so that the Roomba can clean up Stack Overflow as it was designed to do.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=...have,and%20answered%20many%20times%20before.